# Atualizar status sem criar o widget diretamente - Flutter

Tags: flutter, callback, prepared-statement

Tenho no meu main.dart um BottomNavigationBar que deve ficar sempre visivel. Algumas telas não poderão ser acessadas pelos icones do BottomNavigationBar.

Main.dart vvvvv

```
void main() async {
  await _storage.ready;
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final int screen;
  final Widget widget;
  final VoidCallback callback;
  MyApp({this.screen, this.widget, this.callback});
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int _selectedScreen;
  static List<Widget> _screens = <Widget>[
    Home(),
    Pesquisar(),
    VerPedidos(),
    MyAccount(),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int screen) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedScreen = screen;
    });
  }

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.screen != null
        ? _selectedScreen = widget.screen
        : _selectedScreen = 0;
    if (widget.widget != null && widget.screen != null) {
      _screens[widget.screen] = widget.widget;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: _screens.elementAt(_selectedScreen),
            ),
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
              type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
              backgroundColor: ThemeData.dark().primaryColor,
              selectedItemColor: Color(0xffdb6a5f),
              unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
              items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                  label: 'início',
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.search_outlined),
                  label: 'Pesquisar',
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_bag_outlined),
                  label: 'Meus Pedidos',
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.account_box_rounded),
                  label: 'Minha Conta',
                ),
              ],
              currentIndex: _selectedScreen,
              onTap: _onItemTapped,
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

geralmente quando preciso alterar o status de um widget children eu faço uma callback no widget. Mas nesse caso eu não "instancio" o widget.

```
child: _screens.elementAt(_selectedScreen)
```

eu chamo uma função que controla as telas que estão sendo exibidas;

como eu poderia fazer algo do tipo:

```
child: Widget(callback: (){setState((){})}),
```

Comment: Não sei se entendi muito bem... Suas telas estão sendo inicializadas logo no começo. Você tentou na definição delas já definir esses callbacks? Eles são um parâmetro no construtor?

Comment: sim na definição dela (widget que não pode ser acessado pelo bottomNavigationBar) eu tenho um VoidCallBack que eu passo como paramentro para o MyApp.dart. Dentro do main, eu tenho uma lista com as telas do bottomNavigationBar (_screens) e como child do scaffold eu tenho essa expressão ```child: _screens.elementAt(_selectedScreen) ``` . O problema é que por estar manuseando uma lista (e não um widget em si) eu não posso pegar o elemento (Widget) e passar os paramentros para ele, que seria o parametro setState((){})

Comment: Sim, mas o que te impede de configurar o callback já dentro da lista, por exemplo? É o mesmo parâmetro para todas as telas?

Comment: Os widgets que não podem ser acessados pelo BottomNavigatorBar não ficam dentro dessa lista. Eu chamos esses widget por uma parametro no construtor do MyApp(screen: 'tela que vai ficar selecionada no bottomNavigator', widget: (receber o widget que não pode ser acessado pelo bottomNa..))

Comment: e então verifico e o adiciono no indice que corresponde na lista, por exemplo se estou no widget de checar numero de telefone, esse widget vai no indice onde tem myAccount na lista.

Comment: ```if (widget.widget != null && widget.screen != null) {
      _screens[widget.screen] = widget.widget;
    }```

Comment: Para fazer o alteração do estado como deseja, você teria que instânciar a tua tela e salvar a referência do estado dela, por exemplo, 'State<HomePage',,, Mas não é um prática muito legal... Porque você precisa alterar o estado de um outro Widget pelo _BottomNavbar_?

Comment: após ler suas resposta cheguei a conclusão que realmente vou ter que por todas as telas dentro da lista de telas, e não somente as telas do bottomNavigatorBar. Com isso vou conseguir "instanciar" o widget e chamar o callback